# Why does this curl command fail when executed in groovy?

Tags: curl, groovy

This curl command works in the terminal but fails in groovy. I added the err and out out from another question to try and understand why it fails.

```
def initialSize = 4096
def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(initialSize)
def err = new ByteArrayOutputStream(initialSize)
def process = "sh -c curl'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts'".execute()
process.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)
process.waitFor()
println process.text
println err.toString()
println out.toString()
```

The output is "curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information"

Comment: with `sh -c` i have exactly the same error. just remove it and put space after curl.

Comment: The command without a space after `curl` almost certainly does not work in the terminal, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use string for execute, as Groovy will split on whitespace. You have to pass the "shell command" as a **single** argument to `sh -c`.  So right now you a) lack a space between `curl` and the url and b) this will end up as two arguments (and you can not quote for that).

Use a string list instead:

```
['sh', '-c', "curl 'http://...'"].execute()
```

Also on a sidenote: if you just want the content of a url and don't need fancy things (timeouts, auth, ...), you can just as well do:

```
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts".toURL().text
```

Comment: this was driving me crazy. thank you!