# sh -c: Unterminated quoted string error in groovy call

Tags: bash, shell, groovy, arguments, jenkins-groovy

I have researched the issue and I think the problem is that I am calling bash from a variable.

There are some great resources including very similar questions on Stackexchange.

The closest match would be this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190008/sh-c-unterminated-quoted-string-error).

There is an [FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) that tries to help.

I try to call a shell command from groovy script.

Here is a working minimal example:

```
def working()
{
    printf "start\n"
    def cmd = "sh -c 'ls'"
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    proc.waitFor()  
    if (proc.exitValue() > 1) 
    {
        printf cmd + "\nexitcode:" + proc.exitValue().toString() + "\n"
        println "[ERROR] ${proc.getErrorStream()}"
    }   
    printf "end\n"
}
```

Here is the code that gives me a headache

```
def notworking()
{
    printf "start\n"
    def cmd = "sh -c 'command -v ls'"
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    proc.waitFor()  
    if (proc.exitValue() > 1) 
    {
        printf cmd + "\nexitcode:" + proc.exitValue().toString() + "\n"
        println "[ERROR] ${proc.getErrorStream()}"
    }   
    printf "end\n"
}
```

I need to use `sh` in order to call `command`.

My error output is:

```
sh -c 'command -v ls'
exitcode:2
[ERROR] -v: 1: -v: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I am pretty sure that this is due to how the arguemnts are actually split.
I am not able to apply any of the array tips from the other questions / responses.

Having done my due dilligance in researching this I am confident this is not a dublicate.
This is also relevant on a broad basis since it can be useful to anyone using jenkins and developing groovy scripts.

Comment: Is "command" an actual binary or is it some sort of script?

Comment: @UlisesAndréFierro `command` is one of the build in commands, that is also why I need to run through `sh` so it gets interpreted correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this curl command fail when executed in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707382/why-does-this-curl-command-fail-when-executed-in-groovy) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005029/postgresql-unterminated-quoted-identifier/57006208#57006208

Comment: @cfrick yes, definitely a dubicate

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent the split by using an environemnt variable and a different execute function.

```
def cmd = "sh -c \$args"
def proc = cmd.execute(["args=command -v $command_name"], null)
proc.waitFor()
```

I found the documentation for the syntax [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute(java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)).

```
public Process execute(List envp, File dir)
```

User cfrick points out that there is a better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707382/why-does-this-curl-command-fail-when-executed-in-groovy).